# How to embed videos using the video module?

Tags: 7, media

I installed the video module and activated video and video ui modules using Drupal 7:
https://www.drupal.org/project/video

I created a content type with a video field. Now I can upload videos with this content type.

But I am not able to embed a youtube video. I can not find any settings or any embed widget as shown here.

I want to upload videos and I want to embed videos (youtube, vimeo..).
But I can not find any way to embed a video unsig this video module.

Do I have to install further modules?
On the module page you can read:

> Video module allows you to embedded videos from YouTube, Vimeo,
>   Facebook, Vine etc (Drupal 8 only) and upload videos and play using
>   HTML5 video player.

I can not find out how to embed a video using this module. Can you help?
I do not want to use another module, I want to find out how to embed videos using THIS module. Be in mind of this when you write your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Are you required to use the Video module.  Or, are you just looking for a valid way to embed videos into some content?

Comment: I want to find out, why the desciption on the module page is wrong: "Video module allows you to embedded videos from YouTube, Vimeo, Facebook, Vine etc (Drupal 8 only) and upload videos and play using HTML5 video player."

Comment: Are you at all interested in an alternative way of embedding videos without  using a module?

Comment: Not here. You can tell me per mail.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question: I do NOT want to embed a video within the text/body of a node!!!! Instead I want to go to Youtube site and click there under the video on share. There I can copy the embed code of this Youtube video or I can copy the URL of the youtube video. This URL or embed code I want to include into a Drupal field. This is what the module mentioned above does, but not for Drupal 7???

Answer (score 1):

If you install the WYSIWYG module, you can enable a button for embedding videos that have been uploaded using the Video module, and then you can use that button to embed videos into content.

Comment: Is this true for Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes. You marked the question Drupal 7.

Comment: I did not find this button in CK Editor. And how is the video been uploaded? In a node field?

Comment: You have to upload the video into a separate node before it can be embedded. For the button, go to Admin -> Config -> Content Authoring -> WYSIWYG Profiles, then click 'edit' for the profile you want, expand 'buttons', and make sure the 'video' button is checked.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question: I do NOT want to embed a video within the text/body of a node!!!! Instead I want to go to Youtube site and click there under the video on share. There I can copy the embed code of this Youtube video or I can copy the URL of the youtube video. This URL or embed code I want to include into a Drupal field. This is what the module mentioned above does, but not for Drupal 7???

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the Video module is for. It's for handling uploaded videos.

To get a video embed field use [Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field).

> Video Embed field creates a simple field type that allows you to embed videos from YouTube and Vimeo and show their thumbnail previews simply by entering the video's url.